# How to remove the IP address assigned to tap0 creating an udev rule

Tags: linux, networking, udev, qemu, bridge

I would like to remove the IP address (169.254.149.209) that's assigned to tap0 on Linux host os (Devuan 5) at a certain point of the booting process of FreeBSD (the guest os / vm),creating an udev rule like this :

```
/etc/udev/rules.d/01-flush-tap0.rules:

KERNEL=="tap0", ACTION=="add", RUN+="/bin/bash -c '/bin/sleep 5; /sbin/ip a fl dev tap0'"
```

and I've activated it with :

```
udevadm trigger
```

and I've even rebooted and I've launched the freeebd vm. Unfortunately the IP of tap0 didn't disappear. Maybe the log messages below can be useful for you for understanding the reason ?

```
[ 86.952262] bridge: filtering via arp/ip/ip6tables is no longer available by
default. Update your scripts to load br_netfilter if you need this.

[ 88.828606] br1: port 1(tap0) entered blocking state [ 88.828627] br1: port 1(tap0) entered disabled state 

[ 88.828941] device tap0 entered promiscuous mode 

[ 88.829104] br1: port 1(tap0) entered blocking state [ 88.829119] br1: port 1(tap0) entered forwarding state
```

Anyway,give a look at the rule below :

```
70-persistent-net.rules :

This file was automatically generated by the /lib/udev/write_net_rules

# program, run by the persistent-net-generator.rules rules file.
# You can modify it, as long as you keep each rule on a single
# line, and change only the value of the NAME= key.

# USB device 0x:0x (usb)

SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add",DRIVERS=="?*",ATTR{address}=="00:60:70:01:00:bf", 
ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"
```

it uses SUBSYSTEM=="net",but I'm using KERNEL=="tap0". I'm not sure that KERNEL=="tap0" is correct. I suspect that SUBSYSTEM=="net" is better....or ? do you know where is the error ?

Comment: Instead of searching how to remove the address, you should search how not to add it. Usually IPv4LL addresses are handled by Avahi (or one of avahi subcomponents) but various network (NetworkManager...) tools could also do this. They would then have options to prevent its addition or to prevent trying to configure an interface they should not deal with.